# Fastest way of applying a perspective transform

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, bitmap

I have implemented some kind of an augemented reality application. For this, I have to apply a perspective transformation on a Bitmap.

For the first try, I implemented everything with OpenCV, and the result is not so bad. The prespective transformation of my Bitmap takes 140ms in average, but this applies only for a device with reliable hardware resources.

How can I make my transformation faster? Should I try to implement it in OpenGL? Or would it also be faster to apply the transformation in the `onDraw()` function of the `ImageView`? Or any different suggestions?

Comment: If you downvote, would you pls tell me what is wrong with my question?

Comment: Seems a legitimate question to me... I can't help, but you'll probably get more help if you post the code you used for benchmarking

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how your bitmap is being rendered. I am assuming that the `ImageView` renders the bitmap using OpenGL behind the scenes anyway, in which case you want to set the transformation in (or before) the `onDraw` function.

Transforming the bitmap yourself (using OpenCV or OpenGL) and then rendering it again via the `ImageView` is a waste of time, unless the `ImageView` does not support transformations at all (which would be strange).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html
suggests you can just call `ImageView.setImageMatrix`. 
You would need to pass in a perspective projection matrix, which can be created with `Matrix.perspectiveM` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#perspectiveM(float[],%20int,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float) or specified manually (not usually necessary).

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look and let you know about my results